# How to test correlation between two variables with repeated measures?

Tags: r, correlation, traits

I want to check the correlation between two variables (plant traits), but I have replications too. I show you an example before my question:

```
  sample      plant trait.1 trait.2
sample 1  species 1       4      12
sample 2  species 1       4      12
sample 3  species 1       4      12
sample 4  species 2       5      14
sample 5  species 2       5      14
sample 6  species 2       5      14
sample 7  species 3       6      13
sample 8  species 3       6      13
sample 9  species 3       6      13
```

Should I check the correlation between the particular values (4, 5, 6 and 12, 14, 13), or between the whole variables (4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, and 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13)? 
Is it ok to use cor.test in R?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @hczsombor, this appears to be more than a statistics question than a plain R question, you could try to visit stack overflow's statistics forum: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . Since the purpose of the replications is probably to get a better idea on how the (biological? technical?) variability affects the correlation, you could try to calculate the correlation for every replicate separately. Cor.test is testing for association between paired samples, so I wouldn't expect it to return different results between replicates.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on you H0. If you think there is a correlation between "trait.1" and "trait.2" no matter the "species" then a correlation is fine. You have to check some assumptions though depending on the data if you should use "Pearson's r" or "Spearman's Rho".

If you think that there might be a difference in "trait.1" and "trait.2" based on the "species" then a ANOVA is what you looking for, to see if there's a mean difference between the different species.

If you think that there is a logical cause and effect between "trait.1" and "trait.2" you could use a regression. Lets say that "trait.1" is a function of "trait.2" and you want to control for "species". Then y = "trait.1", x1 = "trait.2" and x2 = "species".

So it all depends on your H0 and your question.